# Export frames/images from compressed video

Tags: image-processing, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, codec

I have a compressed movie (mp4) and I want to extract every single frame / image from it. I know that each individual frame of the video only contains the changed pixels regarding to the last keyframe, because of the video compression. But that is exactly what I want. I just want to see those differences. I want to visualy see how the compressor works.

Is there some tool like imagemagick out there what can things like that?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, as far as I can tell, but [Debugging Macroblocks and Motion Vectors](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Debug/MacroblocksAndMotionVectors) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

found a solution by my own using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f image2 -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_P)" -vsync vfr pframe_%04d.png
```